# Verbo Transitivo Direto Predicativo

Tags: pronomes-oblíquos, transitividade-verbal

Tendo como tema o predicativo do objeto, deparei-me com o seguinte exemplo:

> Uns a nomeiam primavera. Eu lhe chamo estado de espírito. (C. D. DE ANDRADE)
>
> Na 1ª oração, o substantivo *primavera* é o predicativo do objeto direto *a*; na 2ª, *estado de espírito* é predicativo do objeto indireto *lhe*.

Fonte: Cunha, Celso. Gramática essencial (Referência essencial) . LEXIKON EDITORA DIGITAL LTDA.. Edição do Kindle. (Pode se visto [aqui](https://books.google.pt/books?id=2mGNDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA88&lpg=PA88&dq=%22Eu%20lhe%20chamo%20estado%20de%20esp%C3%ADrito%22&source=bl&ots=7dqar6CqhN&sig=ACfU3U3_tfoJdF3nvjE6sGW3oquacLlCMQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjXhdK97u7oAhWMlxQKHViWBgYQ6AEwAXoECBUQKQ#v=onepage&q=%22Eu%20lhe%20chamo%20estado%20de%20esp%C3%ADrito%22&f=false).)

Do site Brasil Escola:

> O pronome oblíquo “lhe” é substituto dos objetos indiretos, ou seja, dos complementos que
>   possuem preposição.

Do Caldas Aulete, duas definições:

> [(no.me.ar)](http://www.aulete.com.br/nomear)
>
> v.
>
> 1. Dar nome a; citar o nome de [td. : Só nomeou a peça depois de escrita.]
>
> [(cha.mar)](http://www.aulete.com.br/chamar)
>
> v.
>
> (...)
>   11. Dar ou atribuir nome, apelido etc. a [**tdp.** : Os pais a chamaram Ana em homenagem a avó.]

A abreviatura "[tdp.](https://issuu.com/lexikoneditora/docs/abreviaturas_aulete)" é usada pelo dicionário para indicar ocorrência de verbo transitivo direto e predicativo.

A minha questão inicial com o exemplo da gramática era o uso do pronome "lhe" (Por que não seria "Eu a chamo estado de espírito"?). E das definições encontradas do verbo chamar, essa foi a que me pareceu ser a mais próxima do sentido original. Se for mesmo esse o sentido empregado, o que essa transitividade significa? Ou seja, o que é um verbo transitivo direto predicativo?

Comment: Interessante. Possivelmente há várias regências. Aqui em Portugal, nós diríamos como o C. D. Andrade: "Eu lhe chamo estado de espírito".

Comment: Sem dúvida. Só me pergunto por que é "lhe" na segunda oração.

Comment: Porquê, não sei. Claramente Drumond usa  *chamar* como transitivo indireto, como a própria gramática diz. Essa é a regência comum em Portugal de *chamar* nesse contexto. No Brasil o que eu esperaria era "eu **a** chamo **de** estado de espírito" (aceção 12 do Aulete, que me parece mais apropriada que a 11). O Drumond pode ter-se inspirado num escritor português, ou talvez brasileiro antigo. Poetas!

Comment: Excelente questão!! Agora eu também fiquei curioso, não lembro de ter aprendido a esse respeito

Comment: mjfneto, vê se gosta da minha edição do teu título; se não gostares é só clicares em "edit" e fazer "rollback" ou mudares à tua vontade. Eu achei útil referir "chamar" no título porque é o ponto central da questão. Permite outras pessoas com a mesma dúvida encontrar facilmente a pergunta (*chamar* é o único verbo que admite predicativo do objeto indireto). Outra coisa. Notei que aceitaste a minha resposta mas não lhe deste voto positivo. Naturalmente estás no teu direito. Mas há algum ponto que eu possa esclarecer melhor?

Comment: Rollback e voto positivo. Achei justo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na aceção relevante, o verbo *chamar* admite uma carrada de regências: *chama-a jeitosa, chama-a de jeitosa, chama-lhe jeitosa, chama-lhe de jeitosa*.  Cito a *Nova Gramática do Português Contemporâneo* de Celso Cunha e Lindley Cintra (Lisboa, 2014, p. 647-9; nas fontes dos exemplos omito a obra e página):

> 3º [Chamar, n]o sentido de «qualificar», «apelidar», «dar nome», constrói-se:
>
> *a*) com OBJETO DIRETO + PREDICATIVO:
>
> > O povo **chamava-o maluco**. (José Lins do Rego.)
>
> […]
>
> *b*) com OBJETO DIRETO + PREDICATIVO (precedido da preposição *de*):
>
> > **chamaram-no de mentiroso, de ingrato e de vítima.** (Carlos Drumond de Andrade.)
>
> *c*) com OBJETO INDIRETO + PREDICATIVO:
>
> > **Chama-lhe amizade, se preferires**. (Fernando Namora)
>
> *d*) com OBJETO INDIRETO + PREDICATIVO (precedido da preposição *de*):
>
> > **Chamava-lhe** sempre **de miúdo.** (Luandino Vieira.)

A construção com objeto indireto (sem *de*) é de longe a mais comum em Portugal. De facto, não a encontro no dicionários brasileiros, mas encontra-se em autores brasileiros. Alguns exemplos (negrito meu):

> O pessoal da imprensa **chamava-lhe “Chicharro”**, porque diziam que ele estava morto e não sabia;
>   [Érico Veríssimo, *O Resto é Silêncio*](https://books.google.pt/books?id=43FfAAAAMAAJ&q=%22chamava-lhe%20Chicharro%E2%80%9D&dq=%22chamava-lhe%20Chicharro%E2%80%9D&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjC8umXi_ToAhXL0eAKHYLkDsYQ6AEIKDAA)
>
> Nada mais curioso, por exemplo, do que a definição que ele dava da fraude. **Chamava-lhe o braço esquerdo do homem**; 
>   [Machado de Assis, *A Igreja do Diabo*](https://books.google.pt/books?id=YKldDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT21&dq=%22Chamava-lhe%20o%20bra%C3%A7o%20esquerdo%20do%20homem%E2%80%9D&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiP-cTxjPToAhWB3eAKHQ81AdAQ6AEIPTAC#v=onepage&q=%22Chamava-lhe%20o%20bra%C3%A7o%20esquerdo%20do%20homem%E2%80%9D&f=false)
>
> Fora disso, o mancebo praiano achava Cajazeiras de uma insipidez horrível, como ele mesmo dizia, carregando muito no ível. **Chamava-lhe a Terra do Silêncio**.
>   [Manoel de Oliveira Paiva, *Dona Guidinha do Poço*](https://books.google.pt/books?id=Qa12DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT53&dq=%22Chamava-lhe%20a%20Terra%20do%20Sil%C3%AAncio%E2%80%9D&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiXyuWZjfToAhVC8eAKHackDGkQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22Chamava-lhe%20a%20Terra%20do%20Sil%C3%AAncio%E2%80%9D&f=false)
>
> O primeiro teimou, o segundo não cedeu, até que um deles **chamou ao outro pedaço d’asno**
>   [Machado de Assis, *Bons Dias*](https://books.google.pt/books?id=qiY-CQAAQBAJ&pg=PT172&dq=%22chamou%20ao%20outro%20peda%C3%A7o%20d%27asno%E2%80%9D&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi0_oefjPToAhXEUMAKHf5TDxAQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22chamou%20ao%20outro%20peda%C3%A7o%20d'asno%E2%80%9D&f=false)

Comment: Chamo e essa de uma excelente resposta!

Comment: @artu-hnrq, obrigado. Quando se encontra uma gramática que nos faz a papinha toda, é mais facil.

Answer (score 1):

A regência do verbo chamar é mais complexa do que se pensa, não havendo também unanimidade entre todos os gramáticos. O verbo chamar apresenta uma pluralidade de significados, podendo atuar como verbo transitivo direto, transitivo indireto, transitivo direto e indireto, intransitivo e pronominal.

Este vídeo explica os dois casos https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C69DS85xdNI

Comment: Isso não exatamente responde a questão, mas interessante saber! O vídeo não trata a transitividade pronomial.. essa que eu gostaria de conhecer